# Говорить речь или толкать?

Tags: словосочетание

Хотел бы узнать, как правильно выразиться: говорю речь или толкаю? В случае поздравления на свадьбе.
Однажды, беседуя, я сказал: "...и вот я речь говорю...", разговор шел о прошедшей свадьбе, меня поправили, мол, не говорю а толкаю речь!

Comment: @Рафаэль, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

"Толкать речь" - выражение, употребляемое в ироничном смысле или кругу молодежи.
Действительно, говорить о своей собственной речи, произнесенной на свадьбе "речь говорю" звучит слегка неуместно в данном контексте.
Вообще же, правильным выражением является "произносить речь", то оно употребляется в торжественных случаях или же если речь идет о каком - то формальном событии. "Речь произносят" политики, крупные бизнесмены, "речь произносят" при открытии конференции и т.д.
На свадьбе "произнести речь" может лишь "крупная шишка" или всеми очень уважаемое и почитаемое лицо.
Так что если вдуматься, к "свадебному контексту" выражение "Толкать речь" подходит, пожалуй, лучше всего.
Вообще же в данном случае может было бы самым уместным сказать "я сказал", без употребления слова "речь". Но это уже дело вкуса.